# Segregate same columns into two columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with columns:

- Id- unique id for each name
- Name- client name
- Date- account opening date

Sample table:

| Id | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | a | 8/7/2022 |
| 102 | b | 6/6/2022 |
| 101 | a | 16/8/2022 |
| 104 | d | 13/8/2022 |
| 105 | e | 23/4/2022 |

Query I am using:

```
Select id, name, 
Max(date) over (partition by id) as max,
Min(date) over (partition by id) as min
From table
```

Output:

| Id | Name | Date | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | a | 8/7/22 | 16/8/22 | 8/7/22 |
| 102 | b | 6/6/22 | 6/6/22 | 6/6/22 |
| 101 | a | 16/8/22 | 16/8/22 | 8/7/22 |
| 104 | d | 13/8/22 | 13/8/22 | 13/8/22 |
| 105 | e | 23/4/22 | 23/4/22 | 23/4/22 |

The question is to divide the date column into maximum date and minimum date. But with that also where ever there is same date for that I need that date only in max column with null in min.

- clear understanding of the question can be done from expected output.

Expected output:

| Id | Name | Date | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | a | 8/7/22 | 16/8/22 | 8/7/22 |
| 102 | b | 6/6/22 | 6/6/22 |  |
| 101 | a | 16/8/22 | 16/8/22 | 8/7/22 |
| 104 | d | 13/8/22 | 13/8/22 |  |
| 105 | e | 23/4/22 | 23/4/22 |  |

If there is help for this question, then do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IFF function or Case Statement

```
;With SampleData As
(
    Select Id, Name, To_Date(Date) AS Date
    From
    (
        Values(101, 'a', '07/08/2022')
            , (102, 'b', '06/06/2022')
            , (101, 'a', '08/16/2022')
            , (104, 'd', '08/13/2022')
            , (105, 'e', '04/23/2022')
    ) AS Data(Id, Name, Date)
)
Select id
        , name
        , Max(date) over (partition by id) as max
        , IFF(Min(date) over (partition by id) = Max(date) over (partition by id)
                , NULL
                , Min(date) over (partition by id))  as min 
From SampleData
```

Please note that my date format is different than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Mova's answer is correct and concise, it also can be expressed as nested select again with a CTE for data:

```
with data(Id, Name, Date) as (
select column1, column2, to_date(column3, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from values
    (101, 'a', '8/7/2022'),
    (102, 'b', '6/6/2022'),
    (101, 'a', '16/8/2022'),
    (104, 'd', '13/8/2022'),
    (105, 'e', '23/4/2022')
)
```

as

```
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    date, 
    max_date, 
    iff(max_date != min_date, min_date, null) as min_date
from(
    select 
        id
        ,name
        ,date
        ,max(date) over(partition by id, name) as max_date
        ,min(date) over(partition by id, name) as min_date
    from data
)
```

| ID | NAME | DATE | MAX_DATE | MIN_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | a | 2022-07-08 | 2022-08-16 | 2022-07-08 |
| 102 | b | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-06 | null |
| 101 | a | 2022-08-16 | 2022-08-16 | 2022-07-08 |
| 104 | d | 2022-08-13 | 2022-08-13 | null |
| 105 | e | 2022-04-23 | 2022-04-23 | null |

or a [CASE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html) can be used instead of the [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html)

```
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    date, 
    max_date, 
    case when max_date != min_date then min_date end as min_date
from(
...
```

this shows we are trying to get a null value in some cases or the value, which is what [NULLIF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html) does, so this can be convert to one short line:

```
select 
    id
    ,name
    ,date
    ,max(date) over(partition by id, name) as max_date
    ,nullif(min(date) over(partition by id, name), max(date) over(partition by id, name)) as min_date
from data
```

and we can reuse the `max_date`, to make the small also, thus:

```
select 
    id
    ,name
    ,date
    ,max(date) over(partition by id, name) as max_date
    ,nullif(min(date) over(partition by id, name), max_date) as min_date
from data
```

Comment: Simeon, can you help with why you used (partition by id, name). Using only (partition by id) would it make any difference?

Comment: I guess it just seemed that way to me, and what with the guideline of "clear understanding of the question can be done from expected output." I had little doubt I had it wrong, the output guided me.